# Handling a fatal error in PHP from an AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax

Quite simply, I want my javascript to be able to react to a fatal 500 error caused by PHP, appropriately to the error.

**My goal is simply** to collect the fatal error message that the script produced, so I can show it on the client side.

Is this in any way possible?

EDIT: cleaned up the question, in case it gets, by chance, it gets searched.

Comment: Modifying js is more convenient, I suggest you use determine if the ajax data contains a certain string "error".

Comment: You can get the raw XHR object in jquery ajax's [onerror handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events), and from that access the HTTP status code+message of the response: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534650%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Haha, Rufus. I used to do this a long time ago, but it is one very messy solution.

Marc B: I will test around with this. If things work as you say they do, then this will solve my problem.

Comment: So, in the end I decided to just forgo the 500 error and display the error using PHP's register_shutdown_function and my own error class.

Comment: Ok, I finished my ajax framework thingy yesterday, and I do still handle 500 errors as 500 errors. I changed my answer to reflect this.

I use ajaxError, and it catches the 500 and exposes the printed text, which in my case is conveniently wrapped in a JSON object =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Processing Fatal Errors in PHP:

```
register_shutdown_function("foo");
function foo() {
  $e = error_get_last();
  if($e & (E_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR)) //all fatal errors
    [handle the error. I turn the error into a json encoded object that is parsed by JS]
}
```

By checking for all fatal errors, you won't trigger the handle for notices or warnings that happened earlier, but didn't stop execution of the script. Hopefully you already handle those.

Side note:

### Handling fatal errors using jQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxError( function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
  [handle 500 error. xhr.responseText will contain the printed text.]
});
$.post( [...] );
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ for more details.

*Final Note:* display errors should be off if you wish to parse JSON, or text will appear before the JSON encoded object.

Comment: your get_last_error() is actually a error_get_last(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `.status` for an AJAX request.

```
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 500)
  {
    //do something
  }
}

ajaxRequest.open("GET","path/file.php?var=variable");
ajaxRequest.send();
```

^in a nutshell

Comment: No, he wants to handle it on the clientside and show the error on the client screen via AJAX. Read it more carefuly!

Comment: His answer is a lower level version of your answer. So I wouldn't discount it that heavily.

He is handling the error with his code.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks to the two people who did give useful answers. It wasn't the end solution, but it lead me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I provided this code to another user, that would be your solution here. Just use the Jquery 1.5 XHR object to receive error states and if it is an error state, to something with it from your javascript code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){

    alert('getting page');
    jqXHR = $.get(
        'index.php', 
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    )
    .success(function(){ alert('second success'); })
    .error(function(){ alert('error'); })
    .complete(function(){ alert('complete'); });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I already knew about this. I'm going to do some testing to see what I can gather from a 500 response if anything. I would prefer to also receive an error message, but I'm not sure if that would happen.

The other tricky part, is that some fatal errors don't trigger 500 errors. They will come back as 200 with the error message in text. This is very bad when my ajax framework handles things using JSON objects.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks to the two people who did give useful answers. It wasn't the end solution, but it lead me to it.